# Angular6 ngIf creates empty element when false

Tags: angular

I have a problem with Anguar6 and ngIf:

```
    <div class="card" *ngIf="pr.cat==='livres'" >
        <img src="../../assets/img/images2.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><b><u>Titre  :</u></b>{{pr.titreD}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text"><b><u>Description :</u></b>{{pr.description}}</p>
            <br><b><u>The donor :</u></b>{{pr.titre}}. {{pr.prenom}}  {{pr.nom}}<br>
            <b><u>Email :</u> </b>{{pr.email}}<br>
           <b><u>Téléphone: </u></b> {{pr.number}}<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Click to view</a>
            <button type="submit" (click)="deleteproduit(i)" class="btn btn-primary">Supprimer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that angular creates an empty bloc with this comment in it:

[inspect element]

Following is the error screenshot.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot for better understanding ?

Comment: @akhil done.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is creating an empty element. the div you see is the outer div. your div with class="card" is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Angular compiler.

ngIf internally gets expanded to ::

`<ng-template [ngIf]="someCondition"></ng-template>`

Angular wraps the host element inside `<ng-template>` and consumes the `<ng-template>` in the finished DOM by replacing it with diagnostic comments.

So, what you are seeing is of the outer div and you are seeing your ngIf block just as a comment(not creating new empty element actually).

Hope, this helps :)

Comment: thank you for the answer !
can you please show me what should i change in my code? :)

Comment: Nothing to change buddy.. I was just saying that a new element is not actually getting created. What you are seeing is actually a comment

Comment: If you got your answer, then please accept the answer by clicking on the ✔ icon below the question to close the loop. 

Comment: actually i'm still waiting for a someone who can correct my code

Comment: Ok.. but as mentioned above, its just a comment which will not weigh anything in your DOM and nothing needs to be change in your code.. its done by the Angular compiler itself.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

***ngIf** is a structural directive that shall control DOM manipulation. If your condition is false, then that element (div in this case) shall not be rendered at all.

Placing comments is a default behaviour of angular compiler. Why it places comments? This way angular knows where embedded view will be placed in DOM.

In your code the div you are seeing is the outer div, the div you have *ngIf is not rendered.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you sir for the answer!
can you please edit my code so it can works?